# How to properly get the error messages from recaptcha using Flask after submit a form

Tags: flask, recaptcha

I am creating a Form that contains a reCAPTCHA v2 using the [flask-recaptcha](https://github.com/mardix/flask-recaptcha)  and I am having some problems to get the error message when the person has clicked on the submit button without checking the reCAPTCHA. It should not show an error message initially, but when submitted without the reCAPTCHA, a message should now appear. A common feature when validating forms.

As I am learning flask, I am using this tutorial as an example (https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/03-Forms-and-Validation).

Usually for the other fields, like the username, the following code is used:

```
  {% if form.username.errors %}
     {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
     <div class="invalid-feedback">
      {% for error in form.username.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
      {% endfor %}
     </div>
  {% else %}
     {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
  {% endif %}
```

Taking the same idea, I would like to have something similar to the previous case, which shows the error message just when an error occurs, after trying to submit without checking the recaptcha. Obviously, the following code does not work

```
{% if form.recaptcha.errors %}
     {{ form.repactha }}
     <div>
      {% for error in form.recaptcha.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
      {% endfor %}
     </div>
  {% else %}
     {{ form.recaptcha }}
  {% endif %},
```

What I have for now is a workaround really ugly, as following

```
<div>
       {% if not form.recaptcha.verify %}
         {{ form.recaptcha }}
            <div>
              <span>Please, don\'t forget to click on the captcha</span>
            </div>
       {% else %}
         {{ form.recaptcha }}
       {% endif %}
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is that the message always appears while the recaptcha is not valid (even on the first execution).

How can I improve this?

Comment: Can you include your Python code so others can test and reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sure. I will do that to help. But I think the main idea here is when a user clicks the submit button, how to show an error message as the form.recaptcha.errors does not exist